# The question is related to deploying of cloud functions in gcp?

Tags: typescript, function, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have 8 cloud functions in gcp project and source code is in the git hub repo. If I want to deploy functions then the following error is getting:
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Function 'onAIModelUpload' is not defined in the provided module.
Could you please help me out of this issue?

Whenever the function is deployed if we change any modifications also always it needs to be successful.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Which language do you use?

Comment: Yes I have checked the logs and it is showing as follows: ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Function 'onAIModelUpload' is not defined in the provided module.

Comment: So, you have your error. You have to fix this.